# Why cannot use weka.classifiers.functions.PLSClassifier

Tags: java, weka

I am trying to use weka's PLSClassifier using java, but when I tried to import weka.classifiers.functions.PLSClassifier into eclipse, it gives me error(The error is import weka.classifiers.functions.PLSClassifier cannot be resolved). The weka I use is the latest version3.7, but I found no class PLSClass under weka.classifiers.functions.
The documentation for this class is:     http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/PLSClassifier.html
I would like to know do I need addition package to support this?

Comment: _it gives me error_. What error?

Comment: The error is import weka.classifiers.functions.PLSClassifier  cannot be resolved.

Comment: Have you added the weka jars to the build path?

Comment: Yes. I have weka.jar in the reference. I think my weka.jar works fine since I used KNN of it and KNN works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found an external PLSClass package and solve the problem. It seems that in the original weka library, there is no PLSClass under weka.classifiers.functions package.